# What is the genre of music in the Kitchen Swagger playlist on Spotify?

Tags: identify-this-genre, spotify

What is the genre of music in the [Kitchen Swagger playlist](https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DX2FsCLsHeMrM?si=42K0MRGERtyr3VVSb0BAWQ) on Spotify?

> Lost in Paris - Tom Misch
>   I Wish I Missed My Ex - Mahalia
>   Closer - Corinne Bailey Rae
>   How Deep is Your Love - PJ Morton & Yebba
>   MPB - Womack & Womack
>   It Runs Through Me - Tom Misch & De La Soul
>   Soulmate - MMYYKK
>   Why Don't You Call Me Anymore - Prince
>   The Sweetest Meditation - Lord Echo
>   Petit Prince Du Macadam - Folamour
>   Loose Tonight - Hips
>   Jeri Curl - Cam O'bi
>   Calm Down - Burna Boy
>   Bad Bad News - Leon Bridges
>   The Look of Love - Maydie Myles
>   Summer - The Carters
>   Tints - Anderson.Paak
>   Conexao - Amber Mark
>   Doing Better - Jamie Isaac
>   Starlight Groove - Lex One & Lucian White
>   My God Has a Telephone - Flying Stars of Brooklyn
>   Over You - Macy Gray
>   February 3rd - Jorja Smith
>   Gonna Love Me - Teyana Taylor
>   ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is mostly ["Alternative R&B"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_R%26B)** (sometimes called "PBR&B" or hipster R&B).  R&B ("rhythm & blues") is the long-running catch all term used by the Billboard charts for music aimed at the black American audience --but it has meant many very different sounds over the years.  "Alternative R&B" began to be used as a term in the 90s to mean neo-soul, which was a retro revival of the soul sound of the 70s, but with some more modern sensibilities. Neo-soul started in the mid 90s as a more organic, less synthesized, less aggressive and beat-driven alternative to the black pop chart hits. It is still an active genre today, but modern alternative R&B now often also includes elements of hip-hop, EDM and indie rock.  In addition to its core black American community of artists and fans, it is also popular among young Brits of all colors.

In addition to neo-soul (Lauryn Hill, Angie Stone, India.Arie), and PBR&B (Tom Misch, Shawn Mendes, Anderson.Paak) this particular list also includes some actual classic soul (Luther Vandross, Bill Withers) and a bit of retro funk.  Mostly this is music created by, with, or in imitation of young black American musicians, just a little bit outside the mainstream pop charts, over the last 30 years --**with some exceptions**.

I'd expect this playlist to be popular among younger Gen Xers or older Millennials, particularly if they are African-American or prefer African-American music. It's a little chill, but not overly so --**lively enough to keep you awake and grooving**, but not really "get up and party" music.